# Proof of Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus case (second case)

Tags: calculus, integration

In the first part of the proof of FTC 2, we show that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt$, for any $x \in [a,b]$, then $F'(x) = f(x), \forall x \in [a,b]$ for the case where we let $x \in (a,b)$ be arbitrary. What is a general proof for the second case, when $x=a$ and $x=b$? I believe the proof is similar to the first case where $x$ is arbitrary, but for case 2, I think the limits in the proof would no longer be 2 sided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly right. In fact, for any function $h$, if $h$ is undefined outside of $[a, b]$, then $h'(a)$ must be defined by a one-sided limit (and so must $h'(b)$). This applies to the function $F$ just as much as to any other.

Comment: So for the subcase x=b, we want to show $F'_{-}(b) = f(b)$, and for the subcase x=a, we want to show $F'_{+}(a) = f(a)$ what would $ F'_{-}(b)$ and $ F'_{+}(a)$ be equal to in the first line of the proof? I'm confused on this part

Comment: Since I don't have your particular version of the proof in front of me (I learned the FTC so long ago that there weren't yet well-established "parts", etc.), I cannot answer this.

Comment: @Shrek.Spongebob: without any further information you can start with definition of $$F'_{-} (b) =\lim_{x\to b^{-}} \frac{F(x) - F(b)} {x-b} =\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{h}\int_{b-h}^{b}f(x)\,dx$$

Comment: @Shrek.Spongebob: you should write a similar limit for $F'_{+} (a) $ and show that these limits are equal to $f(b) $ and $f(a) $ respectively. You will also find that we don't need continuity of $f$ on whole of $[a, b] $, we just need it at the point where we wish to find derivative of $F$.